# Stability and capacity, error in the book of Adams-Hedberg?

Tags: sobolev-spaces, potential-theory, stability

I am struggling to understand the proof from the book of Adams and Hedberg, "Function spaces and potential theory". It seems to me that there is a serious flaw, and moreover, the statement is incorrect. However, I am not an expert in the field of potential theory, and I want to ask somebody to verify those thoughts of mine.

The theorem I am interested in is Theorem 11.5.10 on p.335. To recall its statement, I recall that a set $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is called $(1, 2)$-stable if the following identity between Sobolev spaces hold
$$
W_0^{1,2}\big(\operatorname{int}(E)\big) = W_0^{1,2}(E),
$$
where the set $W_0^{1,2}\big(\operatorname{int}(E)\big)$ is defined as the closure of the smooth functions of compact support in $\operatorname{int}(E)$, and $W_0^{1,2}(E)$ is defined as the set of functions $f \in W_0^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with vanishing trace on the complement of $E$. Remark that the trace here is defined by using quasi-continuous representatives.

The statement Adams and Hedberg are making in Theorem 11.5.10 a),d) states that the $(1,2)$-stability of a Borel set $E$ is equivalent to the divergence of the sum
$$
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} 2^{n - 2} N_{1,2}\big(B(x, 2^{-n}) \setminus\operatorname{int}(E) ; B(x, 2^{-n+1})\big), 
$$
for (1,2)-quasi every $x \in \partial E$. The quantity $N_{1,2}\big(B(x, 2^{-n}) \setminus \operatorname{int}(E) ; B(x, 2^{-n+1})\big)$ is defined as some sort of modified capacity, which, according to Proposition 11.5.9, is bigger that the classical capacity $C_{1,2}\big(B(x, 2^{-n}) \setminus \operatorname{int}(E)\big)$, defined for a given closed set $D$ by 
$$
C_{1,2}(D) = \inf\left\{\| f\|_{1,2} : f \in W^{1,2}_{0}(\mathbb{R}^n),  f \geq 1 \text{ on } D\right\}.
$$

I think that the correct statement would be that the $(1,2)$-stability of a Borel set $E$ is equivalent to the divergence of the sum
$$
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} 2^{n - 2} N_{1,2}\big(B(x, 2^{-n}) \setminus E ; B(x, 2^{-n+1})\big), 
$$
for (1,2)-quasi every $x \in \partial E$, which is significantly weaker. The proof, presented by Adams and Hedberg, as it seems to me, shows exactly that, see the beginning of the p. 324. I think the counterexample for the statement of Adams and Hedberg would be the compact set $K$ from Theorem 11.5.5.

In the notes for this chapter, Adams and Hedberg say that this result is due to Netrusov, but his paper was never published...